# custom recipes for python for android

Tags: kivy

I have written a python module with linked C code and would like to include it in a kivy project. I wrote a `recipe.sh` and added it to `.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/recipes/mypackage` Everytime I run `buildozer android debug` my new folder is removed from the recipes folder. Then `buildozer` assumes my module is a pure python module and fails to find and add it to a virtualenv.

I worked around this by commenting out a call to `git clean` in the buildozer code, but I would like a more elegant solution. What is the correct way to add new recipes to python for android?

Answer (score 3):

From [python-for-android docs](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contribute/#create-your-own-recipes):

> ### Create your own recipes
>
> A recipe is a script that contain the “definition” of a module to
>   compile. The directory layout of a recipe for a  is
>   something like:
>
> ```
> python-for-android/recipes/<modulename>/recipe.sh
> python-for-android/recipes/<modulename>/patches/
> python-for-android/recipes/<modulename>/patches/fix-path.patch
> ```
>
> When building, all the recipe build must go to:
>
> ```
> python-for-android/build/<modulename>/<archiveroot>
> ```
>
> For example, if you want to create a recipe for sdl, do:
>
> ```
> cd python-for-android/recipes
> mkdir sdl
> cp recipe.sh.tmpl sdl/recipe.sh
> sed -i 's#XXX#sdl#' sdl/recipe.sh
> ```
>
> Then, edit the sdl/recipe.sh to adjust other information (version,
>   url) and complete build function.

Comment: My problem is that buildozer runs `git clean` and removes my custom recipes from `python-for-android/recipes/`

Comment: Ooh, OK.. Well that would (according to me) be a new issue on github: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues

Comment: Thanks. I just saw the issue is already there: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/76

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the buildozer.spec, it says it clearly if you don't define the path it clones it for you

> buildozer.spec

```
# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =
```